# How to group array entries in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this sample data and transformed it into an array of objects like the one below. This has two levels: Level1, and Level2.

```
var array = [{
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 1"
}, {
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 2"
}, {
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 3"
}, {
  "Level1": "Location1",
  "Level2": "SubLocation 1"
}, {
  "Level1": "Location1",
  "Level2": "SubLocation 2"
}];
```

I want to group it by their Key, and below it will be the name/values of the key. (see sample below). How will I fix this so that in my HTML it will be.

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Assigned to</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Assigned To 1</p>
    <p>Assigned To 2</p>
    <p>Assigned To 3</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Location</h3>
  <div>
    <p>SubLocation 1</p>
    <p>SubLocation 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So far I am trying to fix this code, but I am only getting the Level1 values `var uniqueLevel1 = {};
$.each(json, function() {
    uniqueLevel1[this.Level1] = this.value;
});
$.each(uniqueLevel1, function(l1) {
    $('#details').append('<h3>' + l1 + '</h3>');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`$.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can iterate through the array and get values, them manipulate them.

```js
var json = [{
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 1"
}, {
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 2"
}, {
  "Level1": "Assigned to",
  "Level2": "Assigned To 3"
}, {
  "Level1": "Location1",
  "Level2": "SubLocation 1"
}, {
  "Level1": "Location1",
  "Level2": "SubLocation 2"
}];

var LevelArray = []
$.each(json, function(i, val){
  //console.log(val);
  var className =  val.Level1.replace(/\s/g);
  if($.inArray(className, LevelArray) == -1){
    LevelArray.push(className);
    var thisLevel = $('<div>',{
      'class' : className
    });
    thisLevel.append($('<h3>').text(val.Level1));
    var thisRow = $('<div>').append($('<p>').text(val.Level2));
    thisLevel.append(thisRow);
    $('body').append(thisLevel);
  } else {
    var thisLevel = $('.' + className )
    thisLevel.find('div').append($('<p>').text(val.Level2));
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Rejith, I have updated my question. the <p> should be inserted inside a <div>
I will be using this with the accordion in jquery UI

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use `_.groupBy`
`_` is Lodash library https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy. You can use it like this:

```
var result = _.groupBy(array, function(elem){
      return elem.Level1;
   }
);
```

As a result you will get the object like this:

```
{
   "Assigned to": [here array of all objects with Level1 === 'Assigned to'],
   "Location1": [here array of all objects with Level1 === 'Location1']
}
```